# How to cast [String:Int] to [String:Double]

Tags: swift, dictionary, int, double, type-conversion

I have a function that requires a dictionary in the format `[String:Double]`, but my data is currently a `[String:Int]`.

I'd really like to be able to convert the dictionary using a one-liner, such as

```
let doubles = ints as! [String:Double]
```

But that doesn't seem to work, giving the error message `Cannot convert value of type '[String : Int]' to type '[String : Double]' in coercion`

Whilst I'm sure I could work around the problem, I'd really like to understand

1. Why I can't convert '[String : Int]' to '[String : Double]'
2. What method I should use (perhaps something like `.map` would work?)

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
for (key, value) in dictionary {
    newDictionary[key] = Double(value)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any reason why the `as! [String:Double]` doesn't work automatically though?

Comment: You can't cast `Int` to `Double` directly anymore in Swift. You need to create  each object with `Double(int)`